# What version of Apache Sling does Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) 6.2/6.3 use?

Tags: adobe, aem, sling

I was wondering what version of Apache Sling does Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) 6.2/6.3 use?  I've searched on various sites, including Adobe's own documentation, but haven't seem to be able to find a definitive answer to this.

At the moment I'm interested in which version org.apache.sling.servlets.get AEM 6.2/6.3 is using, but in the future I'll likely need to know other packages as well.

Thanks for any leads!

Comment: Sling is a set of coherent API working together. You can search for individual package version via AEM's sling console.

Comment: Fair enough...I found the Sling Console.  However, I've looked under the different sections and don't see an answer to my question.  Also, you say that Sling is a _coherent API working together_.  The newest version of Sling from Apache's site seems to be version 8.  Are you saying that version is made up of smaller pieces?  If so the question is how to find out those smaller pieces...perhaps @Danzinger is working on the solution below...

Comment: Sling 8 is the specification. All revisions are backward compatible to a large extent. If your question is about which Sling API version is implemented by a specific AEM version then the marked answer is misleading.

Comment: The answer was what I was going for; I updated my question for clarity.  I wasn't aware that "Sling 8" was a specification when I asked my original question.  I was more interested in specific bundles it seems.  Thanks for the info about the specification though.

Comment: I think this question is perfectly valid and not yet answered. What Sling API Docs should one refer for AEM 6.3? https://sling.apache.org/documentation/apidocs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have the versions for `6.2`, but keep in mind that depending on your installed Feature Packs, versions may vary. Mine are not GA either, so you may see some versions that don't match the ones on the initial releases.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
}

th, td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Symbolic Name</th>
<th>AEM 6.2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Adapter Manager Implementation</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.adapter</td>
<td>2.1.6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling API</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.api</td>
<td>2.11.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Atom Tag Library</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.atom.taglib</td>
<td>0.9.0.R988585</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Authentication Service</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.auth.core</td>
<td>1.3.14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Background Servlets Engine</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.bgservlets</td>
<td>1.0.6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Bundle Resource Provider</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.bundleresource.impl</td>
<td>2.2.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Commons FileSystem ClassLoader</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.commons.fsclassloader</td>
<td>1.0.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Commons HTML Utilities</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.commons.html</td>
<td>1.0.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Commons Java Compiler</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.commons.compiler</td>
<td>2.2.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Commons OSGi support</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.commons.osgi</td>
<td>2.4.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Compat Servlets</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.servlets.compat</td>
<td>1.0.0.Revision1200172</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Content Detection Support</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.commons.contentdetection</td>
<td>1.0.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling DataSource Provider</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.datasource</td>
<td>1.0.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling DavEx Access to repositories</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.jcr.davex</td>
<td>1.3.4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Default GET Servlets</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.servlets.get</td>
<td>2.1.14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Default POST Servlets</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.servlets.post</td>
<td>2.3.8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Discovery API</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.discovery.api</td>
<td>1.0.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Discovery Base</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.discovery.base</td>
<td>1.1.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Discovery Commons</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.discovery.commons</td>
<td>1.0.10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Discovery Support Bundle</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.discovery.support</td>
<td>1.0.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Distributed Event Admin</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.event.dea</td>
<td>1.0.4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Distribution API</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.distribution.api</td>
<td>0.3.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Distribution Core</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.distribution.core</td>
<td>0.1.15.r1733486</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Dynamic Class Loader Support</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.commons.classloader</td>
<td>1.3.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Engine Implementation</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.engine</td>
<td>2.4.6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Event Support</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.event</td>
<td>4.0.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Feature Flags</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.featureflags</td>
<td>1.0.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling File Installer</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.installer.provider.file</td>
<td>1.1.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Health Check Core</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.hc.core</td>
<td>1.2.4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Health Check Support Components</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.hc.support</td>
<td>1.0.4.1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Health Check Webconsole Plugin</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.hc.webconsole</td>
<td>1.1.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Initial Content Loader</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.jcr.contentloader</td>
<td>2.1.10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Installer Configuration Admin Support</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.installer.factory.configuration</td>
<td>1.1.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Installer WebConsole Plugin</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.installer.console</td>
<td>1.0.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Installer</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.installer.core</td>
<td>3.6.8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Internationalization Support</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.i18n</td>
<td>2.4.6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Inventory Printer Based on Resources</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.resource.inventory</td>
<td>1.0.4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling javax.activation bundle</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.javax.activation</td>
<td>0.1.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling JCR Base Bundle</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.jcr.base</td>
<td>2.3.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling JCR Installer</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.installer.provider.jcr</td>
<td>3.1.18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling JCR Repository Registration</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.jcr.registration</td>
<td>1.0.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling JCR Resource Resolver (Adobe Vendor Branch)</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.jcr.resource</td>
<td>2.7.4.B001</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling JCR Resource Security</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.jcr.resourcesecurity</td>
<td>1.0.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling JMX Resource Provider</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.jmx.provider</td>
<td>1.0.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling JSON Library</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.commons.json</td>
<td>2.0.16</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling JSP Tag Library</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib</td>
<td>2.2.4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Launchpad Installer</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.launchpad.installer</td>
<td>1.2.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Log Tracer</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.tracer</td>
<td>1.0.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Metrics</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.commons.metrics</td>
<td>1.0.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling MIME type mapping support</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.commons.mime</td>
<td>2.1.8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Models API</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.models.api</td>
<td>1.3.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Models Implementation</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.models.impl</td>
<td>1.3.9.R1787388</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Models Model Exporter - Jackson</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.models.jacksonexporter</td>
<td>1.0.6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Oak-Based Discovery Service</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.discovery.oak</td>
<td>1.2.6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling OSGi LogService Implementation</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.commons.logservice</td>
<td>1.0.6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Repository API Bundle</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.jcr.api</td>
<td>2.3.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Resource Access Security</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.resourceaccesssecurity</td>
<td>1.0.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Resource Collection API</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.resourcecollection</td>
<td>1.0.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Resource Merger</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.resourcemerger</td>
<td>1.3.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Resource Resolver</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.resourceresolver</td>
<td>1.4.16</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Rewriter</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.rewriter</td>
<td>1.1.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Scheduler Support</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler</td>
<td>2.4.14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Scripting Core implementation</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.scripting.core</td>
<td>2.0.36</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Scripting Implementation API</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.scripting.api</td>
<td>2.1.8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Scripting Java Support</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.scripting.java</td>
<td>2.0.14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Scripting JavaScript Support</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.scripting.javascript</td>
<td>2.0.28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Scripting JSP Support</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp</td>
<td>2.1.8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Scripting JST Support</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.scripting.jst</td>
<td>2.0.6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Scripting Sightly Engine</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly</td>
<td>1.0.18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Scripting Sightly JavaScript Use Provider</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.js.provider</td>
<td>1.0.10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Scripting Sightly Models Use Provider</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.models.provider</td>
<td>1.0.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Security</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.security</td>
<td>1.0.18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Service User Mapper</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.serviceusermapper</td>
<td>1.2.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Servlet Helpers</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.servlet-helpers</td>
<td>1.0.1.R1755308</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Servlet Resolver</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver</td>
<td>2.4.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Settings</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.settings</td>
<td>1.3.8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Simple WebDAV Access to repositories</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.jcr.webdav</td>
<td>2.3.4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling SLF4J Implementation (Logback)</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.commons.log</td>
<td>4.0.6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Startup Filter Disabler</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.startupfilter.disabler</td>
<td>0.0.1.Rev1387008</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Startup Filter</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.startupfilter</td>
<td>0.0.1.Rev1526908</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling System Bundle Extension: WS APIs</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.fragment.ws</td>
<td>1.0.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling System Bundle Extension: XML APIs</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.fragment.xml</td>
<td>1.0.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Tenant</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.tenant</td>
<td>1.0.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Thread Support</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.commons.threads</td>
<td>3.2.6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Validation Framework API</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.validation.api</td>
<td>1.0.0.R1698284</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Validation Framework Core Implementation</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.validation.core</td>
<td>1.0.0.R1698283</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Web Console Security Provider</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.extensions.webconsolesecurityprovider</td>
<td>1.1.6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apache Sling Wrapper Bundle for the JCR API</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.jcr.jcr-wrapper</td>
<td>2.0.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HApi - Sling Hypermedia API tools</td>
<td>org.apache.sling.hapi</td>
<td>1.0.0</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

To check them in your own AEM installation, go to the AEM Web Console here: http://localhost:YOUR_PORT_HERE/system/console/bundles. You will see something like this:[image]

Comment: At the moment I'm interested in org.apache.sling.servlets.get, but in the future I'll likely need to know more, hence the broader question - a full table would be excellent.  And also where you found it so you can teach me how to fish as well.  :)

Comment: This is excellent; I was only looking under the Sling menu and not under the OSGi menu.  I see that the Bundle information is found under the OSGi menu.  That makes sense now that I understand more about this and how Sling is a conglomeration of multiple components.  Thank you for the screenshots and code as well!

Answer (score 1):

To answer @Cris Rockwell's question "What Sling API Docs should one refer for AEM 6.3?" the [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/reference-materials.html) recommends Sling 9 to AEM 6.3 and Sling 10 for AEM 6.4